# Import Arabic font to React Material Theme

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to use Noto Sans Arabic font in my React material UI theme. 
The theme is working well, overrides are working too.

I have tried  [React Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/) to import my fonts like in react-material documentation, but it doesn't work:

```
import notoArabic from '../static/fonts/NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf'

....


const arabic = {
  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans Arabic',
  fontStyle: 'regular',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 400,
  src: `
    local('Noto Sans Arabic'),
    local('Noto Sans Arabic-Regular'),
    url(${notoArabic}) format('ttf')
  `,
  unicodeRange:
    'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF',
};

...

overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        '@font-face': [arabic],
      },
    },

...
```

I expect that the font will be imported and work.

I have any errors, and can see font-family: Noto Sans Arabic; in my browser. But it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Do the arabic characters show at all (and not as squares)? Or only the font is not being imported?

Comment: I mean that fontFamily not imported.

Comment: @Hubi in the React Material docs that you have referred to, the code given creates a **theme**, specifying the font-family prior to the overrides; have you included such code? (there seems to be a bit missing from your code) If you can see font-family:Noto Sans Arabic in your code, then it has been imported, it's just not being applied correctly

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own react material theme wrapper and override a lot of styles, such as buttons, theme-colors, etc.

Comment: export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Noto Sans Arabic, regular", 
///

I have such code in my theme

Comment: @Hubi Please add relevant code to your question. By the way, I only saw your comment now, because I revisited this question. In future, tag me in responses by adding the `@` symbol and my name (as I did here for you). That way,  I will see that you've replied to my comment.

Comment: @RachelGallen what you mean "relevant code" ? I did the same that docs says. My app sees fontstyle Noto Sans Arabic. But doesn't import the font from imported file :(

Or tell me please what additional info you need

Comment: @Hubi I mean if you have the theme created, you should have included that in the code that you pasted into your question (instead of skipping bits of code). The errors in your code may be in omitted pieces of code

Comment: @RachelGallen I can't understand. You want to see all my 900 lines of theme styles ? 
Overides are working. I see the new font in my styles when do the  upper code. But font is not imported

Comment: @Hubi **relevant** code, that means the pertinent theme style.

Comment: @Hubi an example with https://codesandbox.io that shows the issue will be much helpful

Comment: What IDE are you using, does it have a TTF loader? I'm assuming you have been self-hosting previous fonts so you would have caught on by now if it didn't...

Comment: Dear @Hubi, Is my answer correct? I'm confused, you assign the bounty but do not assign the tick, Does the answer have issue?

Comment: @AmerllicA yes. It really works. I fixed what I want to fix. But now it is really interesting, why the material docs variant is not working :)

Comment: @Hubi, because they are not from a land with RTL language.

Comment: @AmerllicA but anyway it font, doesn't matter what region it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Persian and our language fonts very very look like Arabic fonts. for my project, I create a separated file, and I named it `globalStyles.js`:

```js
import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import yekanRegularTtf from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebregular.ttf';
import yekanRegularWoff from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebregular.woff';
import yekanRegularWoff2 from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebregular.woff2';
import yekanBoldTtf from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebbold.ttf';
import yekanBoldWoff from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebbold.woff';
import yekanBoldWoff2 from '../app/assets/font/iranyekanwebbold.woff2';

const globalStyles = ({ spacing, typography, colors }) =>
  createStyles({
    '@global': {
      '@font-face': [
        {
          fontFamily: 'IRANYekan',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: 400,
          src: `url(${yekanRegularWoff2}) format('woff2')`,
          fallbacks: {
            src: [
              `url(${yekanRegularWoff})`,
              `url(${yekanRegularTtf}) format('truetype')`,
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          fontFamily: 'IRANYekan',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: 700,
          src: `url(${yekanBoldWoff2}) format('woff2')`,
          fallbacks: {
            src: [
              `url(${yekanBoldWoff})`,
              `url(${yekanBoldTtf}) format('truetype')`,
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
      html: {
        lineHeight: '1.5',
        WebkitTextSizeAdjust: '100%',
      },
      '*': {
        transition: 'opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)',
        fontFamily: "'IRANYekan', sans-serif, Arial",
        boxSizing: 'border-box',

        '&:after, &:before': {
          fontFamily: "'IRANYekan', sans-serif, Arial",
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
        },
        '&[type="checkbox"], &[type="radio"]': {
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          padding: '0',
        },
        '&[type="number"]': {
          '&::-webkit-inner-spin-button, &::-webkit-outer-spin-button': {
            height: 'auto',
          },
        },
        '&[type="search"]': {
          WebkitAppearance: 'textfield',
          outlineOffset: -2,

          '&::-webkit-search-decoration': {
            WebkitAppearance: 'none',
          },
        },
        '&[hidden]': {
          display: 'none',
        },
        '&::-webkit-file-upload-button': {
          WebkitAppearance: 'button',
          font: 'inherit',
        },
      },
      body: {
        fontFamily: "'IRANYekan', sans-serif, Arial",
        lineHeight: '1.38',
        margin: 0,
      },
      '#react-view': {},
      'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6': {
        margin: [[0, 0, spacing.margin]],
        lineHeight: '1.3',
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textTransform: 'none',
        color: colors.black,
        display: 'block',
        fontFamily: "'IRANYekan', sans-serif, Arial",
      },
      h1: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize * 1.4,
      },
      h2: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize * 1.2,
      },
      h3: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize,
      },
      h4: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize,
      },
      h5: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize,
      },
      h6: {
        fontSize: typography.fontSize,
      },
      p: {
        display: 'block',
        margin: [[0, 0, spacing.margin]],
      },
      main: {
        display: 'block',
      },
      hr: {
        boxSizing: 'content-box',
        height: 0,
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
      pre: {
        fontSize: '1em',
      },
      a: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        textDecoration: 'none',
      },
      'b, strong': {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
      small: {
        fontSize: '80%',
      },
      img: {
        borderStyle: 'none',
      },
      button: {
        WebkitAppearance: 'button',
      },
      input: {
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
      'button, input, optgroup, select, textarea': {
        fontFamily: 'inherit',
        fontSize: '100%',
        lineHeight: '1.15',
        margin: 0,
      },
      'button, input': {
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
      'button, select': {
        textTransform: 'none',
      },
      textarea: {
        overflow: 'auto',
      },
      'button, [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"]': {
        WebkitAppearance: 'button',

        '&::-moz-focus-inner': {
          borderStyle: 'none',
          padding: '0',
        },
        '&:-moz-focusring': {
          outline: [[1, 'dotted', 'ButtonText']],
        },
      },
      fieldset: {
        padding: '0.35em 0.75em 0.625em',
      },
      legend: {
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        color: 'inherit',
        display: 'table',
        maxWidth: '100%',
        padding: '0',
        whiteSpace: 'normal',
      },
      progress: {
        verticalAlign: 'baseline',
      },
      details: {
        display: 'block',
      },
      summary: {
        display: 'list-item',
      },
      template: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
  });

export default globalStyles;
```

And in the top level of my components, I injected to the project root component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { CssBaseline, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import SnackBarProvider from './SnackBar';
import globalStyles from '../utils/globalStyles';
import { generalHelmet } from '../utils/helmetConfig';

type AppProviderProps = {
  children: any,
  store: any,
};

const AppProvider = ({ children, store }: AppProviderProps) => (
  <>
    <Helmet {...generalHelmet} />
    <CssBaseline />
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <SnackBarProvider>{children}</SnackBarProvider>
    </ReduxProvider>
  </>
);

export default withStyles(globalStyles)(AppProvider);
```

Also, in the Webpack configuration file I wrote the font loader just like below:

```js
~~~

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isDev = nodeEnv === 'development';
const exclude = [/node_modules/, /public/];
const name = isDev ? '[name].[ext]' : '[hash:5].[ext]';
const publicPath = '/assets/';

~~~

module.exports = {

  ~~~

  module: {
    rules: [

      ~~~

      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
        exclude,
        loader: 'url',
        options: { limit: 10240, name, publicPath },
      },
```

And everything works well now. I hope my configuration helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try few things as mentioned below to check if you are compiling code properly.

1. From the related URL which you mentioned to import the font infers that the `static` folder and `above file` directory are **siblings**. Make sure, the related path are same as per `root` folder.
2. Also, if you're using `webpack` to bundle your code, make sure you include `ttf` file extension and add `file-loader` module to handle it during [compiling](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

e.g.

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  query: {
    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities but I would suggest trying loading the same font via your index.css file and check the result, Could it be the location you are referring is not correct or the font isn't present.

Also a file-loader or plugin might be required to render fonts with webpack read: https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack

Comment: The question was about how to do it with Material UI, but anyway I need to import fonts. So I'll try late. Maybe I will ask more questions, okay?